# How to align text or content in GridView (ListView) columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I want to declare `GridViewColumn` in `ListView` this way:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sells}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="No. of order" Width="80"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NoOfOrder, StringFormat=N0}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="100"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat=N0}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="100"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat=N2}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But the problem with this is the column headers as well as the cells don't align in the way I want them to, I've several `ListView` in my app and I want some of their column headers as well as cells to be aligned center and others to be right and the solution I've found on this site is to do something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Buys}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="No. of order" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NoOfOrder}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Quantity" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat=N0}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Price" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat=N2}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

That's a lot for a 3 column `ListView`! I've some other that have 7/8 columns so it definitely will be a pain to rewrite all of them like this! Is there a way to declare these `ListView` in the way I defined in the first example for `Sells` and have some templating and binding mechanism so that I can write those columns this way:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sells}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="No. of order" Align="Center" Width="80"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NoOfOrder, StringFormat=N0}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Align="Right" Width="100"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat=N0}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Align="Right" Width="100"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat=N2}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to write an Attached Behavior. This implementation uses two properties. `ListView.IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabled` must be set on the `ListView` and `ListView.ColumnContentAlignment` of type [`TextAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.textalignment?view=netframework-4.8) on the corresponding `GridViewColumn` (if this property is not set the value will default to `TextAlignment.Left`).

This is because there is no easy way to get the parent `ListView` of a `GridViewColumn`.

The following Attached Behavior allows to align any `FrameworkElement` (not only `TextBlock` elements):

**ListView.cs**

```
// Attached Behavior
public class ListView : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ListView), new PropertyMetadata(false, ListView.OnIsColumnContentAlignmentEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsColumnContentAlignmentEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) => attachingElement.SetValue(ListView.IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsColumnContentAlignmentEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(ListView.IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  #region ColumnContentAlignment attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnContentAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ColumnContentAlignment", typeof(TextAlignment), typeof(ListView), new PropertyMetadata(TextAlignment.Left, ListView.OnColumnContentAlignmentChanged));

  public static void SetColumnContentAlignment(DependencyObject attachingElement, TextAlignment value) => attachingElement.SetValue(ListView.ColumnContentAlignmentProperty, value);

  public static TextAlignment GetColumnContentAlignment(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (TextAlignment) attachingElement.GetValue(ListView.ColumnContentAlignmentProperty);

  #endregion

  private static Dictionary<GridViewColumn, System.Windows.Controls.ListView> ColumnListViewTable { get; }

  static ListView()
  {
    ListView.ColumnListViewTable = new Dictionary<GridViewColumn, System.Windows.Controls.ListView>();
  }

  private static void OnColumnContentAlignmentChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Get the parent ListView of the current column
    if (attachingElement is GridViewColumn gridViewColumn 
      && ListView.ColumnListViewTable.TryGetValue(gridViewColumn, out System.Windows.Controls.ListView listView))
    {
      ListView.AlignColumns(listView);
    }
  }

  private static void OnIsColumnContentAlignmentEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.ListView listView))
    {
      return;
    }

    bool isEnabled = (bool) e.NewValue;
    if (isEnabled)
    {
      if (!listView.IsLoaded)
      {
        listView.Loaded += ListView.InitializeColumnsOnListViewLoaded;
        return;
      }
      ListView.InitializeColumns(listView);
    }
    else
    {
      ListView.UnregisterColumns(listView);
    }
  }

  private static void InitializeColumnsOnListViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var listView = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListView;
    listView.Loaded -= ListView.InitializeColumnsOnListViewLoaded;
    ListView.InitializeColumns(listView);
  }

  private static void InitializeColumns(System.Windows.Controls.ListView listView)
  {
    if (ListView.TryRegisterColumns(listView))
    {
      ListView.AlignColumns(listView);
    }
  }

  private static void AlignColumns(System.Windows.Controls.ListView listView)
  {
    IEnumerable<ListBoxItem> listViewItemContainers = listView.Items
      .OfType<object>()
      .Select(item => listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem);

    foreach (ListBoxItem listViewItemContainer in listViewItemContainers)
    {
      if (!listViewItemContainer.TryFindVisualChildElement(out GridViewRowPresenter rowPresenter))
      {
        continue;
      }

      List<object> rowElements = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(rowPresenter)
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToList();

      for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowPresenter.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
      {
        TextAlignment columnContentAlignment = ListView.GetColumnContentAlignment(rowPresenter.Columns.ElementAt(columnIndex));
        if (rowElements.ElementAt(columnIndex) is TextBlock textBlock)
        {
          textBlock.TextAlignment = columnContentAlignment;
        }

        // Because the TextBlock's width is set to Auto
        // the aligned text will always appear to be left aligned.
        // Therefore set equivalent HorizontalAlignment to compensate.
        // Also setting the HorizontalAlignment enables alignment of all FrameworkElements
        if (rowElements.ElementAt(columnIndex) is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
          frameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment = ListView.GetHorizontalAlignment(columnContentAlignment);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static HorizontalAlignment GetHorizontalAlignment(TextAlignment textBlockTextAlignment)
  {
    switch (textBlockTextAlignment)
    {
      case TextAlignment.Center: return HorizontalAlignment.Center;
      case TextAlignment.Right: return HorizontalAlignment.Right;
      case TextAlignment.Justify: return HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
      default: return HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
  }

  private static void UnregisterColumns(System.Windows.Controls.ListView listView)
  {
    if (!(listView.View is System.Windows.Controls.GridView gridView))
    {
      return;
    }
    gridView.Columns
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(column => ListView.ColumnListViewTable.Remove(column));
  }

  private static bool TryRegisterColumns(System.Windows.Controls.ListView listView)
  {
    if (!(listView.View is System.Windows.Controls.GridView gridView))
    {
      return false;
    }
    gridView.Columns
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(column => ListView.ColumnListViewTable.Add(column, listView));
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
<ListView ListView.IsColumnContentAlignmentEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"
                      ListView.ColumnContentAlignment="Right"
                      Header="First Name" />
      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"
                      ListView.ColumnContentAlignment="Center"
                      Header="Last Name" />
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: with that I've to define same resource in all `ListView`! Is it possible to take that resource to `App.xaml` so that I can avoid defining that in every `ListView`?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I just chose the `ResourceDictionary` which is closest to the scope to make the code snippet concise.

Comment: There's another problem, sometimes it's `NoOfOrder`, sometimes `Quantity`, `Price`, `Value`, etc. How can I parameterize those binding in `App.xaml`?